# When the PDF signing process is completed, how can I retrieve information from the PDF?

Tags: docusignapi

When the PDF eSignature signing process is completed, how can I get pdf base64 or send to GCP Cloud Storage ?

Can you supply DocuSign Developer API document or RESTful API file ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. ***Thank you!!!***

Answer (score 0):

You can download the signed document(s) and the certificate of completion via the [EnvelopeDocuments:get](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/get/) API call

Answer (score 0):

The following article includes step-by-step instructions on how to do this including code examples in 8 languages:

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/download-envelope-documents/

I recommend downloading a [quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) to get you quickly running, it sets up authentication and includes the above code example as well as others that you may find useful.

The C# code for this is:

```
var docuSignClient = new DocuSignClient(basePath);
docuSignClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);

// EnvelopeDocuments::get.
// Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
System.IO.Stream results = envelopesApi.GetDocument(accountId,
                envelopeId, docSelect);

// Look up the document from the list of documents 
EnvelopeDocItem docItem = documents.FirstOrDefault(d => docSelect.Equals(d.DocumentId));
```